# Why does this dependency error happen on Linux but not windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my Node.js code, I receive the following error when running on Linux, but not on my window machines. I don't change the file structure between the two. Why is this occurring?

```
Error: Cannot find module './app/helpers/textHelper.js'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bdu/work/srid_tool/server.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)”
```

Comment: Check capitalization of paths and filenames or maybe some module is not properly installed in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical answer here is that the capitalization of the path isn't exactly the same in the string as it is in the file system. Most *nix file systems are case-sensitive; Windows' standard file systems are not.

So for instance, if the actual directory is `app/Helpers`, or the actual filename is `texthelper.js`, it won't be a case-sensitive match for that string.

Comment: @ChrisChevalier: As a general guideline always treat filenames as case sensitive - it's the only cross-platform way that works everywhere (admittedly there are potential issues on Windows95 which was fixed in Windows98 and won't work in Windows3.1 but nobody runs those OSes anymore)